# How to highlight specific word in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

All I need is just highlight(or similar way) specific word.
I found myself very often mistyping some word like andorid(android), mian(main) and etc...
I know about spellchecking but it's not I want because it's too big and sometimes bothering me if I did not use English.
Do you have any simple idea?

Answer (score 4):

You can use *"Toggle Mark Occurrences"* by selecting text and pressing `Alt + Shift + O`

Comment: thank you for your reply. but I think I didnt write cleary. What I mean is highlight only word that has wrong spell automatically not by myself. I think maybe there is any feature when I mistyped 'main' to 'mian', then maybe something could let me know.

Comment: @Crisy_b: IF you write anything wrong spelled then eclipse automatically put a red underline on the word.